How can I find the content block location using the Id or Customer Key?
I have a few content blocks created in the content builder but am not able to identify them using the content block key or customer key.
Can you please guide me on any easy process to fetch the content block by Id or Customer Key?

I tried it this way and from DE select add in. It doesn't show up the content block

The easiest way is that you can search it on the search bar in Content Builder. I put the steps and an sample image here so you can visualize how to do it:

Put the Id on the Search bar
Select Id from the cog icon
Sort by Id
Find the content block from the results


